# Can we exclude specific character in alphanumeric javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have alphanumeric regex **/^[A-Za-z\d]{8}$/**
**Case:** I want skip exclude specific character from it lets say E, P and S.

Could anyone enhance this regex to support case I mentioned above

Comment: Though I understand Javascript is not one of them, some languages permit the regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9&&[^EPS]]{8}$`.

Answer (score 5):

You can change your `a-z`s to only include a range of the characters you want to permit:

```
/^[a-df-oqrt-z\d]{8}$/i
```

Another method of doing the same thing is to negative lookahead for the blacklist while using `a-z`:

```
^(?:(?![eps])[a-z\d]){8}$
```

Comment: it worked, thanks for quick response.

Comment: Are you sure it's `t-v` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use range like this

```
/^[A-DF-OQRT-Z\d]{8}$/i
```

- `^` - Start of string
- `^[A-DF-OQRT-Z\d]`

  - `A-F` - Can match any character from `A to F`
  - `F-O` - Can match any character from `F to O`
  - `QR` - Match character `Q, R`
  - `T-Z` - Can match any character from T to Z

---

```js
let matcher = (str) =>{
  let pattern = /^[A-DF-OQRT-Z\d]{8}$/i
  return pattern.test(str)
}

console.log(matcher('abcdeh123'))
console.log(matcher('abcdh123'))
```